# CVE-2021-41617 in Ubuntu Jammy needed

Tags: 22.04

Dear Ubuntu Community,

I have a question regarding CVE-2021-41617 , On https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2021-41617 I can see that a fix for Ubuntu Jammy is needed , but in the changelog https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/+source/openssh/+changelog I can see that CVE-2021-41617 is fixed. Also the security scanners found Ubuntu Jammy vulnerable to the mentioned CVE. Do anyone know why it is still reported for Jammy am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems someone forgot to update the Ubuntu security site, as it seems fixed. I'd trust the changenotes more than the CVE site in this case.

Comment: "security scanners" are notoriously ill-informed and prone to false results. Their output should be considered a first draft for human review.

Answer (score 2):

The available evidence leads to the conclusion that the CVE mitigation patch was indeed applied in 2021, and that the discrepancy has a reasonable explanation.

The patch was seemingly applied at Debian, not by the Ubuntu Security Team. The reference bug number "`(closes: #995130)`" is a Debian bug reference, not a Launchpad bug.

Nothing wrong there -- that's a reasonable place to do the patching, and the patching was done by a developer with plenty of experience with that code and a great reputation at both Debian and Ubuntu. But it does perhaps explain why the Ubuntu tracker didn't notice.

I have [pinged](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/cve-2021-41617/36067) the Ubuntu Security Team to review and decide if any change to their tracker is needed.

Comment: thank you very much for the quick resolution. I'd like to ask about this one https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2020-14145 , here only versions of openssh up to 8.6 are mentioned. In Jammy we have openssh 8.9 do this mean that it is not vulnerable to the mentioned CVE ?

Comment: Please open new Questions for separate issues. Be sure to read the engineer comments, which usually explain the issue (and resolution) better than the volunteers here can.